# Where do I turn off CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the right way to set this? I imagine I could muck with /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake, but somehow that doesn't strike me as the Right Thing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294608/where-do-i-turn-off-catkin_enable_testing?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2018-06-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [the how to of the catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html#configuring-and-running-unit-tests), you can disable `CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING` by using

```
catkin_make -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=0
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2018-06-19**:
Not sure why googling didn't bring that up; thanks.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-19**:
To be fair, it took me a while to find it combined with searching the catkin repo.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-20**:
@jayess: you may want to link to the rendered version of the catkin docs instead: [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html#configuring-and-running-unit-tests). The github link would allow you to link to a specific line though, which may be nice.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-20**:
@gvdhoorn Good point. Updated